# What is best way to use LDAP-based services with Azure AD?

Tags: ldap, azure-activedirectory

How can I connect Plastic SCM, which uses non-secure LDAP, to our Azure AD services for authentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD doesn't support LDAP. However, [Azure AD Domain Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview) [supports secure LDAP (LDAPS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#azure-ad-ds-features-and-benefits). [It will cost you at least ~$100/month.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory-ds/)

If your Azure AD environment is hybrid, synced, federated, etc. - that is, you have at least one on-prem Domain Controller - you can use that DC to provide LDAP. If you're 100% cloud, though, AAD-DS is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, specifically the question is how to support apps not compatible with LDAPS.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't obvious to me. You'll need to upvote this: https://plasticscm.uservoice.com/forums/15467-general/suggestions/18666523-advanced-ldap-support. Also, unencrypted/unsigned LDAP is going away from Windows in a couple months - see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4546509/frequently-asked-questions-about-changes-to-ldap. Clear-text passwords going across the network is a terrible idea.